# How can I await modal form dismissal using Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Using Xamarin.Forms how can I use make an async method that waits for the form to dismiss? If I use

```cs
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);
```

it will return once the animation is finished not when the page is dismissed.

I want a to create modal Task SignInAsync method that return true if sign-in is successful.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do this by triggering an event in your login page and listen for that event before going on, but you want the full TAP support and I second you there. Here's a simple yet working 2 page app that does just this. You'll obviously want to use `ContentPage` custom subclass and have proper methods instead of my quick `Command`s, but you get the idea, and it saves me typing.

```cs
public static Page GetFormsApp ()
{
    NavigationPage navpage = null;
    return navpage = new NavigationPage (new ContentPage { 
        Content = new Button {
            Text = "Show Login dialog",
            Command = new Command (async o => {
                Debug.WriteLine ("Showing sign in dialog");
                var result = await SignInAsync (navpage);
                Debug.WriteLine (result);
            })
        }
    });
}

static Task<bool> SignInAsync (NavigationPage navpage)
{
    Random rnd = new Random ();
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool> ();
    navpage.Navigation.PushModalAsync (new ContentPage {
        Content = new Button {
            Text = "Try login",
            Command = new Command ( o => {
                var result = rnd.Next (2) == 1;
                navpage.Navigation.PopModalAsync ();
                tcs.SetResult (result);
            })
        }
    });
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

The minor drawback is that the `Task<bool>` returns before the end of the pop modal animation, but that's:

1. easy to fix
2. only an issue if you're awaiting that result to push a new modal `Page`. Otherwise, meh, just go on.

Comment: @stephane how "You can do this by trig erring an event in your login page, and listen for that event before going on,"? I messed up about it. becuase async diaog run different thread and how can i handle this event by caller page? do you have any sample about it?

Answer (score 21):

### Override OnAppearing

Firstly, it's worth noting that simply overriding `OnAppearing` in the calling Page may suffice in many circumstances.

```cs
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    ...
    // Handle any change here from returning from a Pushed Page
}
```

(note that the pushed page's `OnDisappearing` override is called *after* the caller's `OnAppearing` - seems a bit backwards to me!)

---

### AwaitableContentPage

Secondly...this is my take on @Chad Bonthuys answer:

```cs
public class AwaitableContentPage : ContentPage
{
    // Use this to wait on the page to be finished with/closed/dismissed
    public Task PageClosedTask { get { return tcs.Task; } }

    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs { get; set; }

    public AwaitableContentPage()
    {
        tcs = new System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    }       

    // Either override OnDisappearing 
    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        tcs.SetResult(true);
    }

    // Or provide your own PopAsync function so that when you decide to leave the page explicitly the TaskCompletion is triggered
    public async Task PopAwaitableAsync()
    {
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
        tcs.SetResult(true);
    }
}
```

And then call it thus:

```cs
SettingsPage sp = new SettingsPage();
await Navigation.PushAsync(sp);
await sp.PageClosedTask; // Wait here until the SettingsPage is dismissed
```

Comment: Nice example! I think minimizing the app and then bringing it back up would set the result of the `TaskCompletionSource` and would return the `Task`, correct? Not sure how you could get around that other than making `AwaitableContentPage` a modal using `PushModalAsync()` and creating your own Back button so you could tell the difference b/w a user clicking the back button vs minimizing the app. Also you would want to override `OnBackButtonPressed` for Android, something like: `protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e) { tcs.SetResult(true); return base.OnBackButtonPressed(); }`

Comment: nice answer, tks

Comment: great answer. Tks for the AwaitableContentPage idea. it works fine and also can be used with "child" that use XAML.
Grazie!

Answer (score 2):

Just thought I would contribute to this one, although it's been a while since it was asked and answered. I built upon the answer by @noelicus. I wanted a generic way to do this with multiple situations so the Task needs to be able to return not just bool but anything. Then, using generics:

```
public class AwaitableContentPage<T> : ContentPage
{
    // Use this to wait on the page to be finished with/closed/dismissed
    public Task<T> PageClosedTask => tcs.Task;

    // Children classes should simply set this to the value being returned and pop async() 
    protected T PageResult { get; set; }

    private TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs { get; set; }

    public AwaitableContentPage()
    {
        tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        tcs.SetResult(PageResult);
    }
}
```

Now, in the page you want to run as modal, you can do:

```
public partial class NewPerson : AwaitableContentPage<Person>
```

and when done, simply do:

```
            base.PageResult = newPerson; // object you created previously
            await base.Navigation.PopAsync();
```

Then, to make it super simple to use, use an extension method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    async public static Task<T> GetResultFromModalPage<T>(this INavigation nav, AwaitableContentPage<T> page)
    {
        await nav.PushAsync(page);
        return await page.PageClosedTask;
    }
```

That's all. Now, in your code, in any page where you want to use this, the syntax ends up simply like this:

```
            Person newPerson = await Navigation.GetResultFromModalPage<string>(new NewPersonCreatePage());

            if (newPerson != null)
                UseNewPersonCreatedByOtherPage();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In my implementation I used:

```
await navigation.PopModalAsync();
```

**Full Example:**

```
private INavigation navigation;
    public LoginPageModel(INavigation navigation, LoginPage loginPage)
    {
        this.navigation = navigation;
        this.loginPage = loginPage;
    }


public bool IsValid { get; set; }

    protected async void ExecuteLoginCommand()
    {
        var loginResult = await AuthenticationHelper.Authenticate(Email, Password);

        var isValid = false;

        if (loginResult != null)
        {

            isValid = true;
        }

   //return isValid;
        AuthenticationResult(isValid);
    }

private async void AuthenticationResult(bool isValid)
    {
        if (isValid)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Logged in");
            await navigation.PopModalAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Failed" + email + password);
            await loginPage.DisplayAlert("Authentication Failed", "Incorrect email and password combination","Ok", null);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer selected and given by @Stephane Delcroix above is awesome. But for anybody willing to push this further, by waiting for a page's completion and returning more structured data in a good MVVM fashion, you could do the following:

By calling an event from the page's OnDisapearing method, this event can then be subscribed by the navigation service which you create, and you can then use the `"TaskCompletionSource"` to wati until your page finishes its work and then complete the task. 
For more details about accomplishing this, [you can check this blog post.](https://doumer.me/xamarin-forms-tips-navigate-to-a-page-and-wait-results/)

Here is the base page's implementation, every page in this demo app inherit this page:

```
public class BasePage<T> : ContentPage
{
    public event Action<T> PageDisapearing;
    protected T _navigationResut;

    public BasePage()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        PageDisapearing?.Invoke(_navigationResut);
        if (PageDisapearing != null)
        {
            foreach (var @delegate in PageDisapearing.GetInvocationList())
            {
                PageDisapearing -= @delegate as Action<T>;
            }
        }
        base.OnDisappearing();
    }
}
```

Here is an overview of the navigation service you should use:

```
public async Task<T> NavigateToModal<T>(string modalName)
    {
        var source = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        if (modalName == nameof(NewItemPage))
        {
            var page = new NewItemPage();
            page.PageDisapearing += (result) =>
            {
                var res = (T)Convert.ChangeType(result, typeof(T));
                source.SetResult(res);
            };
            await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(page));
        }
        return await source.Task;
    }
```

To call this page with the navigation service, you can use the following code:

```
 var item = await new SimpleNavigationService().NavigateToModal<Item>(nameof(NewItemPage));
        Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: Hi, Nice ans. I have one more issue. What if we navigate further to other page. Then OnDisappearing will break the code. Is there a way to know when page is disposed?