# Xamarin Forms - how to create a display alert where you can input a quantity?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My app is a online reservation where you can immediately choose your order online and serve it to you in designated time.

How to make this kind of Display alert?
[image: My Design]
Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycSMP.jpg

and instead of "add" i also want "Cancel" button, and
that quantity you input will also transfer to a local variable

Here's my code

**OrdernowMenu.xaml**

```
<ListView x:Name="MyOrder" ItemSelected="MyOrder_ItemSelected" RowHeight="100">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >
                            <Image Source="{Binding menu_image ,StringFormat='https://i.imgur.com/{0:F0}.png'}"  Aspect="AspectFill"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="{Binding menu_name}" Font="30"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding menu_price,StringFormat='₱ {0:F0}'}" Font="20"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding menu_availability} " Font="10" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

**OrdernowMenu.xaml.cs**

```
 public string json_response { get; set; }
        public string tester { get; set; }
        public string seletedMenu;
        public string menuPrice;
        public string quantity;

public OrdernowMenu(Data.PostSender posts1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();


          json_response = posts1.response;
        tester = posts1.teststring;
        GetUserAsync();
    }


private async Task GetUserAsync()
        { 

            var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Menus>>(json_response);

           MyOrder.ItemsSource = user;


        }



        private void MyOrder_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedOrder = e.SelectedItem as Menus;

            if (selectedOrder != null)
                seletedMenu = selectedOrder.menu_name;
            menuPrice = selectedOrder.menu_price;

            //How can i make it just like in the image? and store the value to quantity string
            //DisplayAlert(????);
            //quantity =  ????

        }
```

i tried to research it and i can't find it

my reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/pop-ups

Comment: how are you calling dialog(could you show code)?

Comment: @DmitryZinoviev ItemTapped sorry i'll edit my question for specific details

Comment: it's ItemSelected and if you select an item the popup should display @DmitryZinoviev please see the code i edited my question now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using DisplayAlert or any plugin, you could create your own inputbox dialog method. There is a good thread about this subject in the official Xamarin.Form forum.

there's the link to this thread answered by Thomas Flemming https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/110002/#Comment_110002

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you using this nice plugin:

https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

It let's you create a completely custom popup (it somewhere derives from Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage), using XAML or C# you can create the layout the way you do it for any other page.

Then on clicking the "Add" button, I would return something to the caller of the popup.
I have a basic popup implementation with a return value that you can specify. If you need that code, I can share it here (or check my older answer here: [Getting public variable of popped page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47602421/getting-public-variable-of-popped-page/47621608#47621608))

Basic Implementation:

```
//Create a base callback-popup. Let any popup that should return something on a button click inherit from this
public class CallbackPopup<T> : PopupPage
{
    public Task<T> PagePoppedTask { get { return tcs.Task; } }
    private TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs;

    public CallbackPopup()
    {
        tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    }

    //Deriving classes have to call this method in the "OnDisappearing" or when a specific button was clicked
    public void SetPopupResult(T result)
    {
        if (PagePoppedTask.IsCompleted == false)
            tcs.SetResult(result);
    }
}

//Asyncly call this popup
public async void OpenPopup(){
        var popup = new YourPopup<bool>();
        await Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services.PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(popup);
        bool result = await popup.PagePoppedTask;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be using the Acr.UserDialogs package from NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs/

Include the package into your shared code library and your native implementations, and you can fire up the dialogs with a simple call.

Also I have described a way to create custom dialogs without using external plugins over here: [Display a popup with xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44709571/display-a-popup-with-xamarin-forms/51743006#51743006)

Comment: If you haven't noticed, i added the solution for iOS to the linked post